# Add an element in Observable - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am a beginner in ionic and following tutorials of my lecturer.
I have a ionic 4 shopping application where user can add an item to their wishlist. I am adding just the item id to the wishlist collection in the firebase firestore.
Now, when I am retrieving the wishlist and want to show items inside wishlist, I get the item ids from wishlist collection and then use those item ids to get items from items collection. 
I am stuck at the point where adding the items to another observable or array so I can display those items on the wishlist page. I tried to look at others solutions and they say I have to subscribe or something but I found it difficult to understand so I am posting my question. Below is my code

Interface for items

```
export interface Item { 
  id?: string, 
  name: string, 
  image: string, 
  price: number
}
```

Declaration of wishlist , items, itemsCollection , wishlistcollection and wishlistItems

```
  private items: Observable<Item[]>;
  private itemCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;

  private wishlist: Observable<any>;
  private wishlistCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  private wishlistItems : Observable <Item[]>;
```

Constructor

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
  //save the collection from firebase firestore to itemCollection
  this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection<Item>('items');

  //save the collection from firebase firestore to wishlistCollection
  this.wishlistCollection = this.afs.collection('wishlist').doc(this.userID).collection('items');

  //listen to changes in item collection and save to items
  this.items = this.itemCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    ); 



  //listen to changes in wishlist collection and save to wishlist
  this.wishlist = this.wishlistCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
}
```

Get item code for retrieving the item from items collection

```
getItem(id: string): Observable<Item> {
    return this.itemCollection.doc<Item>(id).valueChanges().pipe(
      take(1),
      map(item => {
        item.id = id;
        return item
      })
    );
  }
```

Now this is the final method that retrieves the items based on itemIDs from wishlist and save to wishListItems

```
getWishlistItems():Observable<any>{

    // get each id from wishlist
    this.wishlist.forEach(item =>{
      //retrieve the item from the items collection
      //but I don't understand how to add it to the wishlistItems since I can't push it to wishlistItems
      this.getItem(item.id);
    })
    return this.wishlistItems;
  }
```

```
Console.log(this.getItem(item.id));
```

gives this

```
{image: "mac.jpg", name: "MAC Cosmetics set", price: 35, id: "3w1HEZ8X11jldlcWkDDx"}
image: "mac.jpg"
name: "MAC Cosmetics set"
price: 35
id: "3w1HEZ8X11jldlcWkDDx"
```

How can I add the items to `wishlistItems` observable?

Comment: What is item do `console.log(item)`

Comment: @PeterHaddad Added console.log result in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getItem()` returns an `observable` which is used in asynchronous code to be able to emit data. Then you can use the `subscribe` method to subscribe to that observable and receive the data:

```
this.getItem(item.id).subscribe(items => {
    console.log(items);
    this.
 });
```

Example in your code:

```
getWishlistItems(){
    this.wishlist.forEach(item =>{ 
    this.getItem(item.id).subscribe(items => {
       console.log(items);
       this.wishlistItems = items;
      });
    });
  }
```

This was the actual code that worked in ngInit() of wishlist page

```
this.crud.wishlist.subscribe(item =>{
      item.forEach(val =>{
        this.crud.getItem(val.id).subscribe(items => {
          this.wishlist.push(items);
        });
      });
    });
```

Therefore change the type of `this.wishlistItems` to any and the type of the method `getWishListItems()`. I'm not sure why you want to return but usually when you `subscribe` to an`observable` to get the values then you just display those values in the template.

Comment: I am doing all this in services and then want to send the wishlistItems to the respective wishlist page. That's why I'm returning it

Comment: Also, a question. items will be one item at a time, so won't this.wishlistItems = items keep changing value of wishlistItems and not really save all my items?

Comment: In the service u only attach an observable, then in the wishlist page you inject the service in the constructor and then subscribe to it

Comment: The best thing is to try it

Comment: It worked. I added the code to ngInit of wishlist page instead of services

Comment: But the part where I said that it'll save just one value at a time was correct. So, please edit your answer for future comers :D